# Why only one (out of two) whitespace was considered as character in the input buffer?

Tags: c, buffer

I am trying to understand how input buffer works. So I wrote a piece of code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a,b;
    char c,d;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    scanf("%c %c",&c,&d);
    printf("%d*%d*%c*%c",a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
    }
```

And now for the input:

```
    5 4 qw
```

So I was expecting my output to be:

```
    5*4* *
```

Output:

```
    5*4* *q
```

Can someone explain me why it considered only one out of two whitespaces (the one in between 5 and 4 & the other one in between 4 and q) as a character and not both of them? And which of the two whitespaces is printed as a character?

Comment: The space is a valid character so it is read

Comment: It is doing exactly what you tell it: read int, space, int, char, space, char, with the first char being a space in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start with

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
```

then that will read the `5` and the `4`, leaving the input buffer as `" qw"`.

Now when you do

```
scanf("%c %c",&c,&d);
```

the first `"%c"` will *read the space*, while the other reads the `'q'`, and the `'w'` will be left in the input buffer.

This is because the `"%c"` format does not skip white-space. It will read *any* character in the input buffer.

If you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the formats `"%c"`, `"%["` and `"%n"` does *not* discard leading white-space.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
scanf("%d %d%c %c",&a,&b,&c,&d);
// input "5 4 qw"
```

`"%d"`: reads/discards leading whitespace (there is none) and then reads/saves as `int` `'5'` -> `5`.
`" "` : reads/discards whitespace (1 space: `' '`).
`"%d"`: reads/discards leading whitespace (there is none) and then reads/saves as `int` `'4'` -> `4`.
`"%c"`: reads/saves 1 character , the space `' '`.
`" "` : reads/discards whitespace (there is none).
`"%c"`: reads/saves 1 character , the `'q'`.

`'w'` remains in `stdin`.

---

If code is not read white-spaces via `"%c"`, precede the specifier with a space.  Also check the return value.

```
//              v
if (scanf("%d %d %c %c",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4) Oh_Happy_Day();
```

Comment: Plus one just for `Oh_Happy_Day()`

Answer (score 1):

With `%d`, `scanf` looks for a number and ignores the spaces but with `%c` the space before `q` is not ignored.